# Do "positive contributions" to get out of question ban include contributions to Meta?

Tags: support, per-site-meta, post-ban

Help Center:

> The ban will be lifted automatically by the system when it determines that your positive contributions outweigh those questions which were poorly received.

Does the "positive contributions" include contributions of Meta?
For example:

1. I am blocked from asking questions on Stack Overflow.
2. I contribute on Stack Overflow Meta.
3. I get to ask on Stack Overflow again because my contributions were positive.

I mean, do things happen like the example?

Comment: [Meta is murder](https://blog.codinghorror.com/meta-is-murder/), anyway, so one could make the joke that *no* contributions to meta are "positive". That's overstating the case, of course, but there's a kernel of truth there, perhaps.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not as far as I've seen - the exact criteria aren't known even to mods.

It is very likely there's *no* weightage from contributing to meta for getting out of a ban. There's no reputation or any real weightage I've seen *anywhere* for it.

The 'sure' things to do are posting *quality* answers and *edits* - these demonstrate an ability to contribute to the site. If you have deleted/closed posts, and they aren't dupes, consider *why* they were closed.

And I'll be frank here - unless you know the 'system' well, you're going to have trouble contributing to meta anyway. If you *did* know the system *you wouldn't get question banned*. As such, it makes little sense for this to work.